# Bluetooth mouse with lag - poor RSSI

Tags: linux, bluetooth, mouse, rssi

Some days ago I start to use a BT mouse. Sometimes its work fine and other times have lag.

After try to check what causes this, and ran several monitoring tools and notice if RSSI is 0 its works fine... but when it decreases, the lag got worst, and lower the RSSI value, worst is the lag.

Because I work in office with lots of wireless equipment, probably with Adaptive Frequency Hooping sometimes it get non clean environment, or the frequency hooping is not working as it should, and not changing to a cleaner frequency.

It is possible, in Linux, to the connection with mouse get stuck to a specific channel/frequency when I manually found one clener?

There is any tool which I can get the channel/frequency the connection is using?

Regards,
Filipe